# JavaRx: can i set default value for observable without subscriber's reaction?

Tags: observable, default-value

I have downloader which send download's percentage through socket to frontend. It looks like this:

```
DownloadStream downloadStream = SomeService.downloadStream(someFile);
Long total = downloadStream.totalSize();
Subject totalDownloaded = new BehaviorSubject.createDefault(0);
Disposable downloadSubscriber = totalDownloaded.subscribe(downloaded -> {
    Message message = new Message(downloaded, total);
    send(message);
});


Long downloaded = downloadStream.stream(); //stream() is bulk read/write.
while(downloaded != -1L) {
    chunk = downloadStream.stream();
    totalDownloaded.onNext(totalDownloaded.value + chunk);
}
```

But problem is that defaultValue=0 invokes subscribe's lambda. How can i define default value without side-effect? Or there is some solution for increment observable long? Please help...

Answer (score 0):

You can remove values using **flatMap()** and **filter()** functions.

Example:

```
    // create sequence
    Observable<Integer> o = Observable.just(0, 10, 25, 32, 56, 74, 100);

    System.out.println("all values:");
    o.subscribe(a -> System.out.printf("%d%%; ", a));

    System.out.println("\n\nfilter by flatMap:");
    o.flatMap(val -> {
                if(val > 5)
                    return Observable.just(val);
                else
                    return Observable.empty();
            })
            .subscribe(a -> System.out.printf("%d%%; ", a));

    System.out.println("\n\nfilter by filter():");
    o.filter(val -> val > 15)
            .subscribe(a -> System.out.printf("%d%%; ", a));
```